# jQuery selector as parameter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this little function to print the image size.
while it works when I just call the function 
with `size('#prototype);` for example, it is not working anymore on `resize('#protoimg)`.

Why? Can anyone help me out, please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function size(a){
    var height = $(a).height(); 
    var width = $(a).width();
    $('#picbox').find('p.size').remove();
    $('#picbox').append('<p class="size">' + width + '-' + height + '</p>');
  }

  size('#protoimg');
  $(window).resize(size('#protoimg'));
)};
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing a character? --> size('#prototype');

Comment: Move $(window).resize wrap out of jQuery's ready wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(function() {
      size('#protoimg')
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        size('#protoimg');
    });

    function size(a){
        var height = $(a).height(); 
        var width = $(a).width();
        $('#target').html('<p class="size">' + width + '-' + height + '</p>');
    }
```

If `#protoimg` is an image file, make sure you set attribute `width="100%"`to avoid overflow.

Comment: thanks, this is working now. i am confused, why it wasn't working with my code, but it works :)

Comment: window.resize was inside jQuery's ready wrap because of which it wouldn't fire on resize.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put to remove the `function size(a)` out of the `$(document).ready();` and put the `$(window).resize();` inside

Like this:

```
 function size(a){
    var height = $(a).height(); 
    var width = $(a).width();
    $('#picbox').find('p.size').remove();
    $('#picbox').append('<p class="size">' + width + '-' + height + '</p>');
  }
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).resize(function() {
    size('#protoimg');
 });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember,the **$(window).resize(parameter)** need a **function** as the parameter.But the **size('#protoimg')** is a result of function.so the correct code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function size(a){
    var height = $(a).height(); 
    var width = $(a).width();
    $('#picbox').find('p.size').remove();
    $('#picbox').append('<p class="size">' + width + '-' + height + '</p>');
  }

  size('#protoimg');
  $(window).resize(function(){
      size('#protoimg');
  });
)};
```